# Trying to invoke facebook login button

Tags: c#, .net

i am trying to invoke the login button but its not invoking

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlElement textElement = webBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("email")[0];
    HtmlElement pass = webBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("pass")[0];
    textElement.SetAttribute("value", "abhinaankumar1493");
    pass.SetAttribute("value", "abh@109");
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("u_0_1").InvokeMember("click");
}

private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.facebook.com");
}
```

i do not know where i am going wrong

Comment: Might not want to post your password.

Comment: Update your question with your login button HTML markup.